# Problem with simple motion with constant acceleration

Tags: physics

I find problems in the Blender physics engine even in simulating simple fall of a sphere. I probably have done some setup wrong because i've also tried bullet engine stand-alone and it works better.

This is the experiment setup:

- 24 fps
- sphere positioned in (0,0,0) with mass 1 kg
- gravity set to (0,0,-10 m/s^2)
- no friction, no bounciness, no damping
- steps per seconds and solver iteration set to 1000

At frame 72 ( 3 seconds ) using the formula [image: costant accelerated motion formula] the sphere should be at -45m but instead it is at -43,76m!
I measured the position snapping cursor to object at selected times.

I thought that there were a constant friction somewhere but i calulated the second derivative to get the acceleration and it's not constant at -10 m/s^2!

**Solved**

i've had to put my animation start from frame 0 instead of 1. Also in Rigid body cache in Scene setting.

Comment: Just checking... your first frame is 0?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I've got -44,98m now. That's enough considered the numerical error made by calculations. Thank you for the hint.